# is there a way to track the number of times a function is called in n seconds?

Tags: python-3.x

Perhaps an odd question but here it goes: I am trying to write an function which

- take no arguments
- return true if this function has been called 3 times or fewer in the last 1 second
- return false otherwise

```py
def myfunction():
        myfunction.counter += 1
    myfunction.counter = 0
```

This above code keeps track how many times this function is called but how to modify this so it satisfy above requirements?

I know that I can use `time` module in python but how to use it to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First keep track of when the function was called with a decorator:

```
import time

def counted(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapped.calls.append(int(round(time.time() * 1000))) # append the ms it was called
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.calls = []
    return wrapped
```

This decorator can be used like so:

```
@counted
def foo():
    print(2)
    time.sleep(.3)
```

Then have a function to group the timestamps within a certain range:

```
def group_by(lst, seconds):
    """
    Groups a list of ms times into the {seconds}
    range it was called.  Most recent grouping will
    be in the first element of the list.
    """
    ms = 1000 * seconds
    result = []
    if lst:
        start = lst[-1]
        count = 1
        for ele in reversed(lst[:-1]):
            if ele > start - ms:
                count += 1
            else:
                result.append(count)
                count = 1
                start = ele
        result.append(count)
    return result
```

Finally test it:

```
for _ in range(5):
    foo()
data = foo.calls
number_of_calls_last_second = group_by(data, 1)
print(f"foo called {number_of_calls_last_second[0]} times within the last second")
print(number_of_calls_last_second[0] <= 3) # Here is your True False output
```

**Output:**

```
2
2
2
2
2
foo called 4 times within the last second
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a decorator like this:

```
import time


def call_counter(calls_number, max_time):
    def _decorator(function):
        def helper():
            helper.calls.append(time.time())
            function()
            if len(helper.calls) > calls_number:
                helper.calls = helper.calls[calls_number:]
                return time.time() - helper.calls[0] > max_time
            return True
        helper.calls = []
        return helper
    return _decorator


@call_counter(3, 1000)
def my_function():
    pass

for _ in range(3):
    print(my_function())  # Prints True three times
print(my_function())  # Prints False: the function has been called four times in less than one second.
time.sleep(1)
print(my_function())  # Prints True
```

I used parameters in the decorator so that you can reuse it with different values. If you have any question, ask me in the comments.